# Exception stops running in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, exception

**Global.asax.cs:**

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();    
    WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
    FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
    RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);

    GlobalFilters.Filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute()); // i added this 
}

protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Exception exception = Server.GetLastError();
    Response.Clear();

    HttpException httpException = exception as HttpException;

    if (httpException != null
    {
        string action;
        switch (httpException.GetHttpCode())
        {
            case 404:
                // page not found 
                action = "HttpError404";                    
                break;
            case 500:
                // server error
                action = "HttpError500";
                break;
            default:
                action = "General";
                break;
        }
    }

    // clear error on server
    Server.ClearError();

    //return new EmptyResult();
}
```

**Action:**

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var a = Convert.ToInt64(""); // I get exception after that project is not running

    return view();
}
```

**Question:**

I'm trying to use dynamic exception in asp.net MVC. In order to do this, I added a method in `global.asax.cs`. Exception handling works, however project does not run after exception occurs.

When I get an exception, I want the project to keep running, like when using a try-catch statement, However when I get the exception, the project stops working.

What to add or what to change **in order for the project to continue running**?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Summary:**

Application_Error does not handle exceptions of the type your code is throwing and even if it did you don't return anything.

**Detail:**

You are trying to use two different aspects of exception handling in ASP.NET MVC.

If you register the `HandlerErrorAttribute` in GlobalFilters then you are saying that for any uncaught error you want to redirect to the Error page of the Application, which by default will be found in the `/Views/SharedFolder`.

But this only works if customErrors="On" in web.config:

```
<system.web>
    <customErrors mode="On" />
</system.web>
```

Note that you can also apply `HandlerErrorAttribute` at the Controller or ActionMethod level rather than globally.

If customErrors="On" **but you do not have an Error page defined** in `/Views/SharedFolder` then it will throw a compounded error of type `System.InvalidOperationException` which in turn will bubble up to Application_Error.

If on the other hand, customErrors="Off" then the `HandleErrorAttribute` mechanics won't fire and instead the exception triggered by your Index ActionMethod will bubble up to the GlobalError handler you have defined in  Application_Error.

In this case the exception will relate to your code:

```
var a = Convert.ToInt64("");
```

This will throw an exception of type `System.InvalidFormatException`.

So if you set a breakpoint in Application_Error you will see that this method does run but it wont actually do anything because your switch statements are only assuming an httpException:

```
 HttpException httpException = exception as HttpException;
 if (httpException != null)
```

httpException will always be null under these circumstances because neither `System.InvalidOperationException` or `System.InvalidFormatException` inherit from `HttpException`.

So you need to be doing something more like:

```
HttpException httpException = exception as HttpException;

if (httpException == null)
{
  // General exception handling logic here
}
else            
{
  // Http exception handling switch statement here            
}
```

That said even if you properly catch and handle the error you're not doing anything with it or after it:

```
//return new EmptyResult();
```

So you will still get a blank page. You should do a Redirect or a Server.Transfer or *something* at this point.

Answer (score 0):

When an exception is raised, it is passed through the call stack until it is caught.
If it is not caught, then the application stops running.

Here you don't try to catch your exception, that's why your application stops running.

All you need is that:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    try
    {
        var a = Convert.ToInt64("");
    }
    catch (YourExceptionType ex)
    {
       // Do something
    }

    return view();
}
```

But you also can use the `TryParse` method, which would avoid using the exception mechanism, which is quite a heavy thing.

Also remember that catching an exception means you know what to do to keep your application in a stable state, even if that exception is raised.

Comment: how can i use try catch dynamic (only 1 try catch in all project ) ?

Comment: That's what the asp.net mechanism lets you do with your error handling method. But this means that the application stops where the error has been raised. This only lets you make an action to show different results to the user depending on the error that you handled, not to continue the execution on the next instruction

Comment: you mean it is imposibble to use try catch once for all project in .net or what do you suggest to use?

Comment: I mean that you can't use a global try catch, and let the execution continue on the next instruction that follows the exception, because execution can only continue at the level of the call stack where the exception was caught

Comment: thanks for helping however not a solution maybe better solution ?

Comment: There is no solution that could handle that kind of things globally. I mean you can't have a global try catch, and hope to return the view at the end of your method. And even if you could do so, it would be a very bad idea, since you could have more errors raised in the view since a value that should have been set will not be

Comment: With a global try catch, the moment the exception is caught, your are no more in the scope of your `Index` method, that's why it can't continue on the next instruction of that method.

Comment: There IS absolutely a solution for that. There's no such thing as global try-catch, but you can use the `HandleErrorAttribute` as explained in rism's answer.

Comment: @ataravati This solution doesn't let the code after the exception to execute, and that's what the question is about here. The "global" try catch would be the higher level try catch. So no, there is no way to let the code after the exception execute except using the try catch locally, or using code injection. And anyway this would ba a bad idea.